# "Undefined method 'close'" when trying to close a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, fclose, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I'm working through "Learn Ruby the Hard Way" and receive an undefined method 'close' error when trying to run the example file here: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html

My code, specifically is:

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV
script = $0

puts "Copying from #{from_file} to #{to_file}."

input = File.open(from_file).read()
puts "The input file is #{input.length} bytes long."

puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exists? to_file}"
puts "Ready, hit RETURN to contine, CTRL-C to abort."
STDIN.gets

output = File.open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(input)

puts "Alright, all done."

output.close()
input.close()
```

The error I receive is only for the last line 'input.close()', as 'output.close()' seems to work fine. For reference, I'm using a preexisting input file, and creating a new output file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're chaining the `read` method on your `open` method, thereby you get the results from `read` returned to `input`, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Also, Ruby 2.0 defaults to UTF-8 - you are not reporting the number of bytes but the number of chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `input` is not a file object because of the `read()` method call:

```
input = File.open(from_file).read()
```

Since `read` returns either `nil` or `""` depending upon the length parameter to [read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read), calling `input.close()` will raise `undefined method close` as `input` in your case is a string and `String` does not have `close()` method.

So instead of calling `File.open(from_file).read()` and calling the `close()` method, you can just call the `File.read()`:

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV
script = $0

puts "Copying from #{from_file} to #{to_file}."

input = File.read(from_file)
puts "The input file is #{input.length} bytes long."

puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exists? to_file}"
puts "Ready, hit RETURN to contine, CTRL-C to abort."
STDIN.gets

output = File.open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(input)

puts "Alright, all done."

output.close()
```

Comment: @bjhaid, please help me understand `With no associated block, File.open is a synonym for ::new` taken from the link you've posted.

Comment: Answer found [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read). It's `read` who closes the file, not `open`.

Comment: You're chaining the `read` method on your `open` method, thereby you get the results from `read` returned to `input`, which is not what you intended.

Comment: @Donovan, so I suppose it's the way I wrote my answer.  I do not think I'm chaining `read` on `open` anywhere.  The first code line is to point out what you've said to the OP.

Comment: Whoops, yea, sorry @vee, I meant that for the OP.

Comment: @bjhaid, no worries.  I would have wished for +1 for the answer instead of anything else :).

Comment: Similar to using `File.read`, instead of opening the file to write, then using `output.write`, just use `File.write(input)`, then discard `output.close()`.

Comment: And, [`File.read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read) reads to the end-of-file and automatically closes the input file. [`ios.read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-read) reads to the end-of-file but doesn't close it. It's an important distinction.